How to not show INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to?
I am saving model with below code.
callbacks = [keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('DeeplabV3Plus', save_best_only=True),
            keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=30, restore_best_weights=True)]

With h5 format, it doesn't show as below.

How can I not show those messages?
I have to save my model without h5 format because h5 format made me error to save.
But those messages come. However, it is fine for model save and load.
I just want to not show those messages.

Hi @MCPMH , To stop TensorFlow from showing informational messages when you save your model, you can change its logging settings to only show important messages like errors.
************Use tf.get_logger().setLevel(logging.ERROR) to only show errors and hide informational messages.
************Use os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2' to also hide warnings

According to @Sagar, answer is as below.
To stop TensorFlow from showing informational messages when you save your model, you can change its logging settings to only show important messages like errors. ************Use tf.get_logger().setLevel(logging.ERROR) to only show errors and hide informational messages. ************Use os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2' to also hide warnings
